# Link âncora com js e bootstrap, como fechar o menu após clicar?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou fazendo um site utilizando boostrap, é uma pagina única.
Quando acesso pelo celular e clico em algum link do menu da página ele faz o efeito de rolagem até aonde está a âncora, mas o menu continua aberto, como posso fazer para ao clicar no link do menu, o próprio menu fechar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso esteja usando jquery, crie uma função que ao clicar transforme o menu em display: none.

`$("#itemmenu").click(function (){
   $("#iddomenuquevcquerquedesapareca").css ("display","none");
});`